# EF Core relationship collection .Count() vs .Count

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a primary entity that contains a collection of related entities (one-to-many). The following is a simplified code example of my scenario:

```
class Secondary {}

class Primary {
  private readonly List<Secondary> _secondaries = new();
  public IReadOnlyList<Secondary> Secondaries => _secondaries;
}
```

In my EF repository i'm trying to project `Primary` into a DTO which contains a COUNT of Secondary entries in its collection:

```
DbContext.Set<Primary>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(primary => new PrimaryDTO{
        SecondaryCount = primary.Secondaries.Count // Access the Count property
    });
```

This query produces an exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
But if i do this instead:

```
DbContext.Set<Primary>()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(primary => new PrimaryDTO{
        SecondaryCount = primary.Secondaries.Count() // Call the Count() method
    });
```

The query works fine. But my IDE says that i should be accessing the property instead of calling the method, and shows the parenthesis next to the Count() call in gray, as if they're redundant. If i follow those instructions my code breaks.

How can one produce a null exception while the other doesn't? Also how can `primary.Secondaries` be null at all if my class initializes it as an empty list? FYI Using `Include()` to load the related collection doesn't alter this behavior.

Comment: Which EF-core version? Please use a tag to indicate it.

Comment: Suppress IDE hint here. You have to use `Count()`

Comment: Some EFC versions have issues translating `Count` property. While `Enumerable.Count()` method translation works in all EFC versions, so it is safer to always use it in projections instead of the property. Ignore the IDE suggestions.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry i forgot to add that; i am using 5.0

Comment: @IvanStoev Gotcha! Will do that thanks

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Will do that, thanks